# integrating init method and @class method together?

Tags: python

```
class bracket:
    a = {"(": ")", "[": "]", "{": "}"}
    d = []

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def check_value(cls):
        for i in self.value:
            if i in cls.a:
                cls.d.append(i)
            elif len(cls.d) == 0 or cls.a[cls.d.pop()] != i:
                return False
        return len(cls.d) == 0
```

in the method `def check_value(cls):` how do I get the `self.value` variable to work which is from `init` method, as per my knowledge dictionary `a` and list `d` are defined outside the `init` method so I am using `@class` method, so how do I integrate both in one function?

Comment: If you want to access instance variables, why is it a class method rather than an instance method?

Comment: firstly i am new to python, second as per your question i am using class method because i have defined a dictionary which is most probably to be fixed and is also defined outside __init__ method, so for accessing that dictionary i am using a class method. also i want to access three values in my check_value() method first the dictionary, second the list to append value and third the self.value from init method.

Comment: None of that is a reason to use a class method. Designating a class method just makes it less convenient to access instance attributes. You could pass one explicitly, like `def check_value(cls, self):` and `bracket.check_value(my_bracket)`, but that defeats the whole purpose. If you need to access instance attributes, just keep it an ordinary instance method. You can still access class attributes from instance methods.

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3 for your explanation; makes a lot sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use class method here! Attributes `a` and `d` should be initialized in `__init__` method because [it is not a good practice](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) to put mutable attribute in the class body.

Comment: okay, i will follow your advice but out of curiosity if i have some situation like this and i want to access __init__ method variable and a dictionary or list which is defined outside the __init__ method, in any other method such as check_value() how will do that?